# How to assign numeric values for the updated selectInput choices in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have used the following code for updating the `selectInput` choices based on the user uploaded data.

```
selectInput("ch_gr1_ma", tags$span(style = "font-weight:normal;", "Choose the first group name"),
                                            choices = NULL, selected = ""),
```

The user uploaded data will look like,

```
structure(list(Samples = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"
), Groups = c("GrA", "GrA", "GrA", "GrB", "GrB", "GrB")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

And in `server` code I have used the following code,

```
observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "ch_gr1_ma",
                      choices = unique(data_groups()$Groups))
  })
```

Then it will give the choices like `GrA` and `GrB` in `selectInput` panel.

How to assign the numeric values to the choices like,

```
selectInput("ch_gr1_ma", tags$span(style = "font-weight:normal;", "Choose the first group name"),
                                            choices = c("GrA" = 1, "GrB" =2), selected = ""),
```

But manually assigning the numeric values is not possible, because the user uploaded data may contain many unique values (GrA, GrB, GrC,....). So how to change the `updateSelectInput` code in the server for the above purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a named vector using `setNames()`:

```
observe({
  grps = unique(data_groups()$Groups)
  choices = setNames(1:length(grps), grps)
  updateSelectInput(session, "ch_gr1_ma", choices = choices)
})
```

Comment: Can I use this code for inputting the observe value of `ch_gr1_ma` in any R function?

Comment: I mean as a one of the input argument of the function. If yes, how to call this value in the function?

Comment: not sure I understand you? Perhaps generate a separate question in SO with explicit examples?, as this question is about `updateSelectInput()`, and already has an answer